# Help with xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have an xml structure like this:

```
<node1>
<node2 name="">
</node2>
<node2 name="">
</node2>
<node2 name="">
</node2>
....
</node1>
```

How can i write an xquery to find if there is a node2 that has name=a

Please help, thank you!

I tried the following but neither seemed to work. What is wrong with these queries?

```
select tbl.query('node1/node2[@name="a"]')
from tbl

select tbl.query('node1/node2[@name=''a'']')
from tbl
```

Answer (score 4):

You'd simply select `/node1/node2[@name = 'a']` (or `//node2[@name = 'a']`) with XPath.

If the select result is empty, there is no matching node.

Comment: i tried this but the result is null even when i know it has a node with that attribute. is there any other way?